# kubectl instead of yaml files in production?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I am trying to find the simpliest method to use kubernetes in production. YAML templates look like an overhead to me. E.g. all I want is expose simple backend service. I can do it with kubectl with 2 lean commands:

```
kubectl create deployment hello-server --image=gcr.io/google-samples/hello-app:1.0
kubectl expose deployment hello-server --type LoadBalancer --port 80 --target-port 8080
```

But is it fine to use this in production? I would like to use Infrastructure-as-a-Code approach.

Is there a way to avoid working with kubernetes template files directly and still follow best practices? E.g. generating Yaml files from docker-compose files or similar?

What is the expected kubectl usage in production? Just

```
kubectl apply -f <folder>
```

while it is developers job to maintain template files in `<folder>` ? Is there a Declarative Management with kubectl without writing kubernetes templates myself? E.g. some files that contain the minimal info needed to templates to be generated.

Really want to use Kubernetes, please advice the simplest way to do this!

Comment: Also have a look at the [flux operator](https://github.com/fluxcd/flux2) that can match the cluster state to the configuration in a git repository. With this, you can just commit the production changes to a repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am quoting the original question here:

> kubectl create deployment hello-server --image=gcr.io/google-samples/hello-app:1.0
> kubectl expose deployment hello-server --type LoadBalancer --port 80 --target-port 8080

> But is it fine to use this in production? I would like to use Infrastructure-as-a-Code approach.

Your first approach is a list of commands, that must be executed in a certain order. In addition, all these commands are not *idempotent*, so you cannot run the commands multiple times.

Also from the original question:

> Is there a way to avoid working with kubernetes template files directly and still follow best practices? E.g. generating Yaml files from docker-compose files or similar?

> What is the expected kubectl usage in production? Just

> `kubectl apply -f <folder>`

The second approach is declarative, you only describe what you want, and the command is idempotent, so it can be run many times without problems. Your desired state is written in text files, so any change can be managed with a version control system, e.g. Git and the process can be done with validation in a CI/CD pipeline.

For production environments, it is best practice to use version control system like git for what your cluster contain. This make it easy to recover or recreate your system.

Comment: Thank you Jonas!
I've updated my question, can you please take a look?

Comment: Why did you remove most of your question? My answer was for your first question. Now the question is very different.

Comment: yes, I did. can you please answer this one. sorry for inconvenience

Comment: I've reverted by my changes in question back and chose your answer as the best one. Thank you!
I've created a separate question https://stackoverflow.com/q/67356177/4685486
Can you please check this one?