# Kubernetes Simple Declarative Management

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Is there a way for more simple Declarative Management than writing template files myself?

E.g. create the template files with kubectl command and then use `kubectl apply` on those templates?

```
kubectl create deployment my-app --image=nginx:latest --replicas=3 --port=8080 --dry-run=client --output=yaml > my-deployment.yaml
kubectl create service loadbalancer my-app --tcp=80:8080 --dry-run=client -o=yaml > my-service.yaml
```

And after this apply the generated template files:

```
kubectl apply -f .
```

Is it OK to use such approach for production?
Or it is considered not a good practice?

Comment: It doesn't matter how you create your YAML files, as long as they are valid. For me, personally, writing them myself seems a lot simpler than using command line to generate them. Also, take a look at [Helm](https://helm.sh/). It can be useful.

Answer (score 3):

While it's quite common to write the individual YAML manifests
yourself, it's less common to apply them individually as you've shown
in your question. Where I work, we use [Kustomize](https://kustomize.io/) to manage our
manifests; this is a tool that assembles a collection of manifests
into a configuration which you then apply all at once using `kubectl apply` (other folks use [Helm](https://helm.sh/), but I don't have any experience with that tool).

There are lots of examples in [the documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/kustomization/), but for your example, you might do something like this:

- Put your deployment manifest in `my-deployment.yaml`
- Put your service manifest in `my-service.yaml`
- Create a file `kustomization.yaml` with the following content:

  ```
  resources:
    - my-deployment.yaml
    - my-service.yaml
  ```

To create or update your resources in the cluster, you run:

```
kustomize build | kubectl apply -f-
```

Kustomize has a number of options for generating things like
`ConfigMaps` and `Secrets` from files, for creating a hierarchical
configuration in which you can override portions of your manifests
with modified content, etc.

Note that a version of Kustomize is actually build into the `kubectl`
command; for the above example, you could have simply run:

```
kubectl apply -k .
```

The version of Kustomize built into `kubectl` is a little older than the standalone version, but for simple configurations it works just fine.

Comment: I also prefer using Kustomize rather than Helm. Helm workflows often turns into imperative scripts.